# Как вызвать метод другого класа в метод мейн?

Tags: ооп, методы

Создал класс `Pupils`

```
namespace Task
{
    class Pupils
    {
        public string name;
        private int age;

        public Pupils()
        {

        }
        public Pupils(string name, int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age; 
        }               
    }
}
```

И есть класс список учеников в классе, хочу добавить туда ученика

```
namespace Task
{
    class Class
    {
        private List<Pupils> Pupils;


        public void AddPupil(Pupils pupil, List<Pupils> pupils)
        {   
            pupils.Add(pupil);
            Pupils = pupils;           
        }
    }   
}
```

В методе `Main` Создаю ученика

```
Pupils pupil = new Pupils("Vlad", 24);
```

Как можно вызвать метод `AddPupil` чтобы добавить ученика в класс? Не вижу метод другого класса если он не статик. 
Что можно сделать? Как изменить когда чтобы добавить ученика в список.

Еще  нужно ли поле `List` в классе Class, или лист нужно будет создавать в `Main`, (при вызове метода  `AddPupil` параметром нужно указать лист, в который хочу добавить)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это че с#? Почему тег не указали? Ну если в двух словах, то нужно создать экземпляр вашего Class, вызвать на нем метод AddPupil и передать в него учеников.

Коллекция конечно же должна быть внутри объекта класс, это же логично, чтоб хранить учеников внутри.
Поэтому логика метода AddPupil не правильная у вас. Смысл передавать в метод объекта коллекцию  класса и ученика,чтоб просто внутри добавить ученика в эту коллекцию, а потом её сохранить, нету. Это очень спецефичный случай. Зачастую вы хотите добавить в класс либо одного ученика, либо нескольких. Поэтому в main создаёте коллекцию, если вам надо, добавляете туда учеников и потом передаёт её в экземпляр класса, то есть сохраняете её в классе.
И последние ваше предложение: указать параметр лист в который я хочу добавить, не совсем понятно. У вас всего один лист в классе

Покажу на примере Java может поможет , у меня там два метода с одинаковым названием AddPupil, они перегружены и срабатывают в зависимости от того какой аргумент в вызове метода, если в с# такого нет, то можно использовать разные названия методов.

```
    class MyClass // в java не используйте слово Class в названии
    {
        private List<Pupils> PupilsList = new ArrayList<>();

        public void AddPupil(Pupils pupil)
        {   
            PupilsList.add(pupil);
                     
        }
//перегруженная версия метода для добавления колекции
public void AddPupil(List<Pupils> pupil)
        {   
           PupilsList = pupil;
/*  
// Либо соединить две коллекции . Тогда нужно будет 
//импорт сделать  библеотеки Stream
//и удалить строку PupilsList = pupil

PupilsList = Stream.concat( 
PupilsList.stream(), pupil.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());   
                   */  
        }

    public void showClass() {
System.out.println(PupilsList);
    } 

    }
```

В методе main создаю экземпляр ученика и класса, чтоб добавить ученика в через вызов метода AddPupil  экземпляра класса MyClass

```
   Pupils pupil = new Pupils("Vlad", 24);
MyClass MyClass1 =  new MyClass();
MyClass1.AddPupil(pupil);
 MyClass1.showClass();
 // JAVA функция для создания листа на лету 
MyClass1.AddPupil(Arrays.asList( new Pupils("Vlad", 24),new Pupils("Dima", 27),new Pupils("Semen", 26)));
  //либо для с#
    //MyClass1.AddPupil(/* ВАШ ЛИСТ УЧЕНИКОВ КОТОРЫЙ ВЫ СОЗДАДИТЕ В MAIN*/) ;
 MyClass1.showClass();
```

Могут быть мелкие синтаксические ошибки так как набирал на телефоне, нет возможности запустить проверить

Arrays.asList - это для удобства, это функция создаёт лист из перечисленных объектов , а так вы должны передать List который в main создадите. В java если после добавления коллекции будете использовать добавление по одному, лучше так не делать. Насколько я помню он создаёт фиксированный лист, и вы не сможете добавить к этому списку ученика . Так что если столкнетесь с такой проблемой используйте в качестве аргумента  метода AddPupil(List pupil) - ArrayList, а не Arrays.asList. Ну то есть в main создаёте полноценную коллекцию и её передаёте. Если использовать будете версию где соединение через stream идёт, то там все равно, кст можно через метод addAll, который есть у листов, соединять, но stream лучше.